# How to align 3 buttons to the bottom of layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I have a linear vertical layout in which I have a TextView.
And three buttons in a line.
I want to put those 3 buttons at the bottom of the layout.
I tried bottom layout but it doesn't seem to work

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msgTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/previousButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Share" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Next" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case the buttons come just below the textview and not at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this>>>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/msgTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
             android:id="@+id/previousButton"
             android:layout_width="0dp" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:text="Previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/shareButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Share" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```